# Android Facebook 4.0 SDK How to get Email, Date of Birth and gender of User

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the following code. I want the user's Date Of Birth, Email and Gender. Please help. How to retrieve those data?

This is my `onViewCreated()` inside the Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Setup TextView.
    mTextDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_details);

    // Set up Login Button.
    LoginButton mButtonLogin = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    // setFragment only if you are using it inside a Fragment.
    mButtonLogin.setFragment(this);
    mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("email");
    mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("user_birthday");

    // Register a callback method when Login Button is Clicked.
    mButtonLogin.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mFacebookCallback);

}
```

This is my Callback Method.

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.d("Shreks Fragment", "onSuccess");


        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        Log.d("Shreks Fragment onSuccess", "" +profile);

        // Get User Name
        mTextDetails.setText(profile.getName() + "");

    }


    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("Shreks Fragmnt", "onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.d("Shreks Fragment", "onError " + e);
    }
};
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata-step3

Comment: Hi, @Sriyank please help me if you resolved your issue. i want to get the user info from facebook signin fragment after login completed want to go next activity please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: the solution below but be careful because the email may be empty if the user is logged via his phone number Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517667/android-facebook-sdk-4-x-how-to-get-email-address-and-facebook-access-token-to and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493486/create-a-request-in-facebook-sdk-4-android

Answer (score 345):

That's not the right way to set the permissions as you are overwriting them with each method call.

Replace this:

```
mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("email");
mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions("user_birthday");
```

With the following, as the method `setReadPermissions()` accepts an ArrayList:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
        "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
```

Also here is how to query extra data GraphRequest:

```
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
            "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                            // Application code
                            String email = object.getString("email");
                            String birthday = object.getString("birthday"); // 01/31/1980 format
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

One possible problem is that Facebook assumes that your email is invalid. To test it, use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cemail&) and try to get it. If even there you can't get your email, change it in your profile settings and try again. This approach resolved this issue for some developers commenting my answer.

Comment: Hey @Schwertfisch can you show how to use object.getString("email"); ,it would be very helpful for me :)

Comment: @Ajeet same way,  String email = "";
        try{
            email = object.getString("email");
        }catch (JSONException exe){
//handle Json exception
        }

Comment: why do I get "No value for email" error despite I already set `loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));`?

Comment: @stackex try debbuging the data, there are two callback objects, graphresponse and jsonobject,  try this, String raw = graphresponse.getRawResponse(); the information string and also you can see something like this in graphobject {"id":"2312312321312312","email":"email@msn.com","name":"Pepito"}

Comment: I use `Bundle parameters = new Bundle(); parameters.putString("fields", "id, email"); facebookRequest.setParameters(parameters);` so I expect the return will be id and email, right? What I got when I print jsonObject and graphResponse is `{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}`. I've checked my account permission, email is checked already.

Comment: @stackex it's extrange. maybe you can try other way. with LoginManager (Without LoginButton). Check FB developers documentation. Maybe it works for you.

Comment: @Sriyank : Did you find solution for this problem, Please help me i'm facing the same issue.

Comment: you can put loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "emai"l, "user_birthday","user_friends");  instead of loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_friends"));

Comment: still facing same issue here with the email. When I login onto facebook, I only have email in the setReadPermissions, when I check the token, under the permissions, only public profile is checked.

Comment: Maybe it's not an issue, I have tried changing the app permissions after was granted in configuration>Apps>some app and i can't get the user information.

Comment: @Schwertfisch in my case, I couldn't get my email even using Graph API Explorer, so I added an alternative email to my account and it worked, maybe your email is invalid.

Comment: @KayanAlmeida :-D it's ok

Comment: @KayanAlmeida wow, finally I solve my issue. your solution works. I need to add additional email to my account. I don't know why, but it finally appears when I request it. :D

Comment: @Schwertfisch Maybe you should edit your answer with this info, it really saves a lot of time! =)

Comment: @KayanAlmeida I don't write a good english explaining, can you do it please and i aprove it.

Comment: @Schwertfisch Done, and reading your answer it's clear to me that you write very good answers! Feel free to change my edit!

Comment: @Schwertfisch how can i fire an intent with these datas, as i want to go on next activity with the object that containing the user data.

Comment: @DevendraSingh you have yo get the values and put them in a extra, Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);myIntent.putExtra("email", object.getString("email"));.....
In the second activity 
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            email = extras.getString("email");
        }
Also you can have a static variable and assign the value. Sorry for my english.
I don't know if this is the answer that you want

Comment: I just have to say That Facebook Docs are so poor! it is a shame we need to find out how to do it here.

Comment: No comments were as clear, you should add an email to the app settings so that Facebook can contact you , thats contact email. Also if you want access to email from other accounts make it public.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you so much for edit and Give link for Graph API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cemail&

Comment: I think  "If even there you can't get your email, change it in your profile settings and try again"  this approach helps me but i am not able to understand where to edit  profile in google account or Facebook account profile. please help me i have stucked from  few hours

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing but my response in the graphapi is as follows {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid OAuth access token.} --- am I missing something, loginResult.getAccessToken() is what I am using

Comment: I can't get email. my json request is like this : {"name":"my name","id":"my id"}

Comment: I've used the same code, but still the callback method is not at all initiated. Can you please tell why it is???
I've have posted my code in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009457/facebook-registercallback-method-not-initiated

Comment: @ParthibanM I just answered your questions, sorry for the delay

Comment: Excelent response!

Comment: Email can be empty even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address (Link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0#reference-email)

Answer (score 12):

You won't get Profile in `onSuccess()` you need to implement `ProfileTracker` along with registering callback

```
mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
    @Override
    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
        // Fetch user details from New Profile
    }
};
```

Also don't forget to handle the start and stop of [profile tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#track_profile)

Now you will have a profile to get AccessToken from (solved the issue of null profile). You just have to use "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata" to get any data.

Comment: But what is the syntax to get the email dob and gender? can u please tell me

Comment: I am getting this as a Access token : {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[user_friends, email, user_birthday, basic_info]} 

I am using this code under FacebookCallBack ----             

AccessToken mAccessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

Can you please tell me what does it means? and how to resolve this error and get Access token?

Comment: @SriyankSiddhartha Do you got any solution for this ?Could you update here ,Facing same issue

Comment: @Sriyank, i'm facing the same issue too, not able to get email id. please help me if you find any solutions. thanks in advance.

Comment: I am still not able to find any solution... I am currently still using old sdk.. please let me know if u get the solution.. thankyou

Answer (score 11):

After Login

```
private void getFbInfo() {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject object,
                        GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "fb json object: " + object);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "fb graph response: " + response);

                        String id = object.getString("id");
                        String first_name = object.getString("first_name");
                        String last_name = object.getString("last_name");
                        String gender = object.getString("gender");
                        String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                        String image_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large";

                        String email;
                        if (object.has("email")) {
                            email = object.getString("email");
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,birthday"); // id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,birthday,cover,picture.type(large)
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Following is the code to find email id, name and profile url etc

```
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
//TODO on click of fb custom button call handleFBLogin()
     callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }

    private void handleFBLogin() {
            AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();

            if (isLoggedIn && Store.isUserExists(ActivitySignIn.this)) {
                goToHome();
                return;
            }

            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(ActivitySignIn.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    setFacebookData(loginResult);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            Toast.makeText(ActivitySignIn.this, "CANCELED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                            Toast.makeText(ActivitySignIn.this, "ERROR" + exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }

private void setFacebookData(final LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        try {
                            Log.i("Response", response.toString());

                            String email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                            String firstName = response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name");
                            String lastName = response.getJSONObject().getString("last_name");
                            String profileURL = "";
                            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null) {
                                profileURL = ImageRequest.getProfilePictureUri(Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId(), 400, 400).toString();
                            }

                           //TODO put your code here
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ActivitySignIn.this, R.string.error_occurred_try_again, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,first_name,last_name");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a working solution (2019):
put this code inside your login logic;

```
 GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                    // Application code
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Success");
                        String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                        System.out.println("JSON Result" + jsonresult);

                        String fbUserId = json.optString("id");
                        String fbUserFirstName = json.optString("name");
                        String fbUserEmail = json.optString("email");
                        //String fbUserProfilePics = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fbUserId + "/picture?type=large";
                        Log.d("SignUpActivity", "Email: " + fbUserEmail + "\nName: " + fbUserFirstName + "\nID: " + fbUserId);
                    }
                    Log.d("SignUpActivity", response.toString());
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Login Attempt Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "An Error Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: whats json there ??

Answer (score 3):

You can use the GraphRequest class to issue calls to the Facebook Graph API to get user information. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph for more info.

Answer (score 3):

This is worked for me, Hope to help someone (Using my own button not FB login button )

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_user);



     LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {


            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("RESAULTS : ", object.getString("email"));
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.i("RESAULTS : ", error.getMessage());
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}

public void signupwith_facebook(View view) {

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line on Click on button

loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                       "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));

Answer (score -3):

Use FB static method getCurrentProfile() of Profile class to retrieve those info.

```
 Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
 String firstName = profile.getFirstName());
 System.out.println(profile.getProfilePictureUri(20,20));
 System.out.println(profile.getLinkUri());
```

Comment: Question is about email, birthday and gender. This doesn't answer any of that.

Comment: this doesn't give email