# Implemention of a Facebook Login Button Sdk 4 android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

So, I'm trying to implement a login Button using Fragment. The documentation on facebook site is just a little bit confusing. My app crashes even on the start. There is no error in build. Here is my code.. If someone can help me I'd be grateful!!

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
   // private Fragment mainfrag=new Fragment();
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private boolean isResumed = false;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
           @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

            }
        };

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/banner" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.moviere.MainFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.17" />
```

**fragment_main.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.moviere.MainFragment">


<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

**and at last MainFragment.java:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginButton loginButton;

public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    // If using in a fragment
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    // Other app specific specialization
// Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**Edit: Android Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.moviere" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

Comment: Try to look at your LogCat log, instead of build log. You may find error message there.  Also, try to request "public_profile" permission instead of a "user_friends".

Comment: The logcat shows only this: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c96c50) . I googled it and it says maybe I'm using a custom package and declare it at Android Manifest. Except for facebook,I',m not using something else.

Comment: Have you declared facebook SDK in [Manifest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#androidstudio)?

Comment: yes, I attached the manifest in my original post as well.

Comment: What i can see, that you have added `meta-data` inside your activity, instead of an `application` tag. From the link above: 
"5. Add a meta-data element to the application element:"

Comment: You're right,I added it inside <application> but the exception is still the same.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong, without certain code error. What I can say, is that this last 4.0 SDK for Android is pretty buggy, I have some issues with it too.

Comment: This video helped me to create Facebook login button for my app  < https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myWu-q8Q2NA > hope it might help anyone else :) ...

Answer (score 2):

I also meet that problem when I study facebook 4.0,and I try again with android studio,I found that app will crash if

> loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager.....

callbackManager is null,so I put

> callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

before

> loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager.....

then run it,it work,I hope it can help you

my simple demo :
https://github.com/oliguo/android-facebook

Comment: Maybe put 'callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();' in your fragment oncreateview function

Comment: @linous maybe you can fork my demo to test it

Answer (score 1):

You have added everything required to integrate Facebook SDK but there is a little bit problem in positioning of code.

You are using `LoginButton` in fragment, but initializing `FacebookSdk` with instance of `Activity`. You need not do anything in activity, just update the code of your fragment like this:

```
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();        
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    ...
    }
}

@Override
... onActivityResult(...) {
    super.onActivityResult(...);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(...);
}
```

Also, start the `ProfileTracker`/`AccessTokenTracker` from `onSuccess()` method of login callback, stop in `onCancel()` and `onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are missing the facebook attribute "xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in fragment_main.xml.

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.moviere.MainFragment">
```

If it does not work i just answered a question using the LoginButton.

[Answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295987/android-facebook-4-0-sdk-how-to-get-email-date-of-birth-and-gender-of-user/29379794#29379794)

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358093/android-login-with-facebook-sdk-4-0/29361346#29361346) post please check the answer accordingly and compare to your code.