# Create a Request in Facebook SDK 4 (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As I understand, Facebook SDK v4 doesn't use the Session anymore, but I read in their Graph API document, the session is still used to create the Request

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3

```
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/me",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

It's confusing me, and how can I get the session for Request? Any latest example to get the user profile data by using Facebook Graph API?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On facebook developers' page is published a changelog and upgrade post. In your case this would be an option:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
                /* handle the result */
            }
    }).executeAsync();
```

By the way, they specify this:

> By default a newMeRequest method fetches default fields from a user object. If you need any additional fields, or want to reduce the response payload for performance reasons, you can add a fields parameter and request specific fields.

For example:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
    accessToken,
    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(
               JSONObject object,
               GraphResponse response) {
            // Application code
        }
    });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

I hope my answer helps you, being this one my first answer in stackoverflow. Greetings.

Reference: [Facebook Android SDK Upgrading](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x)