# How to fix this problem to display email, birthday friends from facebook login?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to login in facebook.
 but I am unable to display the email, friends, birthday. 
I'm missing

> something but unable to find the issues. I think around "request", may be error. please help . [this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HUuQ.png)>
>   Here is the code :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fb_login)

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

        email = findViewById(R.id.txtEmail)
        birthday = findViewById(R.id.txtBirthday)
        friends = findViewById(R.id.txtFriends)
        profile = findViewById(R.id.imgProfile)

        loginButton?.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday","user_friends"))

        loginButton?.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult>{
            override fun onSuccess(loginResutl: LoginResult?) {
                mDialog = ProgressDialog(this@FbLoginActivity)
                mDialog!!.setMessage("Retrieving Data")
                mDialog!!.show()

                request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResutl!!.accessToken, object : GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback {

                    override fun onCompleted(`object`: JSONObject?, response: GraphResponse?) {
                        mDialog!!.dismiss()

                        getData(`object`!!)
                    }

                })

                //Request graph APi

                var parameters : Bundle ?= null
                parameters!!.putString("fields", "id,email,birthday,friends")

                request!!.setParameters(parameters)
                request!!.executeAsync()
            }

            override fun onCancel() {

            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {

            }

        })
    }

    private fun getData(`object`: JSONObject) {
        var profile_picture = URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+`object`.getString("id")+"/picture?width=250&height=250")

        Picasso.get().load(profile_picture.toString()).into(profile)

        email!!.setText(`object`.getString("email"))
        birthday?.setText(`object`.getString("birthday"))
        friends?.setText("Friends :" + `object`.getJSONObject("friends").getJSONObject("summary").getString("total_count"))

    }
```

> Xml file : it displays ui details of facebook login. In this file there is login button of facebook.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp"
        tools:context=".FbLoginActivity">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
    />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:hint="Email"
    />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBirthday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:hint="Birthday"
    />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFriends"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:hint="Friends"
    />      

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The email may be empty if the user is logged via his phone number Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517667/android-facebook-sdk-4-x-how-to-get-email-address-and-facebook-access-token-to and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493486/create-a-request-in-facebook-sdk-4-android

Facebook don't give user birthday by default.You have to use extended permission and submit your app for review to facebook to access user`s birthday.

See here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

Facebook assumes that your email is invalid. To test it, use the Graph API Explorer and try to get it. If even there you can’t get your email, change it in your profile settings and try again.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cemail&