# Android Facebook SDK 4.X , how to get Email address and Facebook Access Token to pass it to Web Service

Tags: java, android, facebook, email

EDIT : 
My Question is how to get Email , UserId , Facebook Authentication with Facebook SDK 4.X , at this moment , with Ming Respond , i know how can i  get Email , User Id , so my question is how to get Facebook Authentication since Session and GraphUser has just been replaced by LoginManager and AccessToken and there is no information about it?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    private String fbUserID;
    private String fbProfileName;
    private String fbAuthToken;
    private LoginButton fbLoginBtn;
    private static final String TAG = "FacebookLogin";
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_activity);
        fbLoginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.connect_with_facebook_button);
        fbLoginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));
        fbLoginBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.connect_facebook_button);


        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                fbAuthToken = currentAccessToken.getToken();
                fbUserID = currentAccessToken.getUserId();


                Log.d(TAG, "User id: " + fbUserID);
                Log.d(TAG, "Access token is: " + fbAuthToken);


            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(
                    Profile oldProfile,
                    Profile currentProfile) {
                fbProfileName = currentProfile.getName();

                Log.d(TAG, "User name: " + fbProfileName );
            }
        };


        fbLoginBtn.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    }

GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                    JSONObject user,
                    GraphResponse response) {
                String id = user.optString("id");
                String firstName = user.optString("first_name");
                String lastName = user.optString("last_name");
                String email = user.optString("email");

            }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }
```

Comment: You need to call callbackManager.onActivityResult in your onActivityResult override, and then add a section in your onSuccess() to make a /me GraphRequest to get the email and userId.

Comment: @Ming , the issue  with the  callbackManager is , when i set it in onActivityResult, after first login , the login button become logout and this is not what i expected so how can i fix this with having callbackManager in onActivityResult?

Comment: @Ming , Could you also please show me with the code how can i use GraphRequest code in OnSuccess , then i will choose your respond as solution of this , Thanks!

Comment: @ming, Sorry to ask here , but i might figure out how to do it so i edited my code and you might correct it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
fbLoginBtn.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        // handle error
                    } else {
                        String email = me.optString("email");
                        String id = me.optString("id");
                        // send email and id to your web server
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // App code
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        // App code
    }
});
```

Comment: perfect , i have noticed this before your post too, but before make your response as a solution , could u please show me how can i access to Facebook Authentication with SDK 4.X too? and then i would choose your respond as a solution of this Thread. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this comment. You're already doing login, what other authentication do you need?

Comment: i think i found it myself in OnSuccess , the loginResult has the AccessToken right? so i just need to add this 'loginResult.getAccessToken().toString()' ? right? because the web service that i work for need to pass Facebook Access Token to web service

Comment: yes, the loginResult will contain the access token, you can also call AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() after the user logs in.

Comment: email is returning `null` always

Answer (score 20):

Easiest answer that i found after hours of searching is as follows,the highest voted answer didn't work for me and email was alway empty

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                            try {
                                if(json != null){
                                    String text = json.getString("email");
                                    Log.d("email",text);

                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
            });
```

I believe setting parameters as required fields to the Graph Request is a crucial thing here. You can also use this code with LoginButton, works without issue.

****** Update********
After using this code with many accounts found that if the email isn't verified it won't be returned, in such case following code helped along with abo

```
facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
```

Hope this helps further

Comment: Works for me, first answer neither is working, emai was always blank

Answer (score 2):

I must add extra field for user Email.

```
    //register facebook login callback
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess (LoginResult loginResult)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "FB: login success");
            showLoading(true);

            final String token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

            //prepare fields with email
            String[] requiredFields = new String[]{"email"};
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", requiredFields));

            GraphRequest requestEmail = new GraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), "me", parameters, null, new GraphRequest.Callback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted (GraphResponse response)
                {
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback callbackEmail = new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted (JSONObject me, GraphResponse response)
                            {
                                if (response.getError() != null)
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "FB: cannot parse email");
                                    showDialog(getString(R.string.dialog_message_unknown_error));
                                    showLoading(false);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    String email = me.optString("email");

                                    // send email and id to your web server
                                    //...
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        callbackEmail.onCompleted(response.getJSONObject(), response);
                    }
                }
            });

            requestEmail.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel ()
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "FB: login cancel");
            showDialog(getString(R.string.dialog_message_unknown_error));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError (FacebookException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "FB: login error " + e.getMessage());
            showDialog(getString(R.string.dialog_message_unknown_error));
        }
    });
```