# save facebook id and email to local database

Tags: android, facebook, android-sqlite

I'm beginning to learn about user login via facebook. In my code there is single layout with FB login button. When user clicks it, it opens the facebook access page and on successful login displays the same layout with profile picture and name. I want to fetch and save email id and facebook user id to local database and on next login check the email id in database to login. This is because, even if user clears data from Settings, user don't have to go to Facebook access page again. It will search local database and login.

SQLite database

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";

    public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_UID + " TEXT"+")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email

        // Inserting Row
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(2));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void deleteUsers() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Button share,details;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    LoginButton login;
    ProfilePictureView profile;
    Dialog details_dialog;
    TextView details_txt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        profile = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
        details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.details);
        login.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");
        share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details_dialog = new Dialog(this);
        details_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_details);
        details_dialog.setTitle("Details");
        details_txt = (TextView)details_dialog.findViewById(R.id.details);
        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                details_dialog.show();
            }
        });


        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
            RequestData();
            share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    profile.setProfileId(null);
                }
            }
        });
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().build();
                shareDialog.show(content);

            }
        });
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
                    RequestData();
                    share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            }
        });

    }
    public void RequestData(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    if(json != null){
                        String text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");
                        details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                        profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Solution :
[Android Facebook SDK 4.X , how to get Email address and Facebook Access Token to pass it to Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517667/android-facebook-sdk-4-x-how-to-get-email-address-and-facebook-access-token-to)

Any how, if user clears the data from the settings, your database will be emptied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helps me in saving me the email and user ids. But how to go to a different layout to display profile on successful login?

Comment: You can store the values in the Shared Preference or Database after successful login and display on the other page.

For Profile picture you can use :
`profilePictureView.setProfileId(fb_user_id);`
which will directly display the profile picture in Facebook ProfilePictureView widget

Comment: So, should I add the Intent in fbloginBtn.setonclicklistener ? I'm sorry to ask as its very new to me. @Ronish.

Comment: You can Use intent on _updateUI()_ method,  So after successful Login user will be redirected to the new activity  
even you can redirect after the data is stored in the database.  
`private void updateUI() {
         Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
         boolean enableButtons = (session != null && session.isOpened());

         if (enableButtons && user != null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

           startActivity(i);   
         } 
     }`

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the reply. You made my day. @Ronish.

Answer (score 0):

there are two scenario's on how this is done

**First:** you let user sign in through facebook and store it's access token(provided by facebook) in `sharedpreferences` and check `sharedpreferences` everytime the user comeback's to your app.
here expiration of access token is taken care by facebook,so you less of a headache on your side.

**Second:** on you're backend take facebook's access token and replace it with you're generated access token, and here you take care of expiration of token on you're remote server.

however,in both cases access token is stored in you're `sharedpreferences` or even if you store it in you're `sqlite` local db(which you shouldn't),upon clearing **app** data from settings both you're `sharedpreferences` and `sqlite` db is cleared,so there no way to confirm user's identity.
Hence user has to login again which is not a bad thing at all & should be allowed to do so.