# Android Facebook SDK AcccessToken problems

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I try to get user  `email` with `AccessToken`, that I get from `Facebook SDK`

1. If I use `Graph API Explorer`'s `AccessToken` I can get `id`, `name` and `email` doesn't matter  if I use Browser or `OkHttp`:

   `"https://graph.facebook.com/" + user_id + "?fields=email,name&access_token=" + access_token_from_graph_explorer`

I get such responce:

```
 {
      "email": "mail@com",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "id": "4545"
}
```

If  I use  `token` taken by `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken()` method, I  don't get `email` in `JSONObject`.

2. Using `Graph Explorer` I can see  my  `id`. I tried to make  request  this  way:

`"https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,name&access_token="`

and this:

`"https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "?fields=email,name&access_token="`

In second variant I've `"Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions...`, while using my `id`. When I tried to use `id` of another `user` I still didn't get  the `email`.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("fields", "email,name");
            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "me",
                    bundle,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            System.out.println("data = " + response.toString());
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
```

With  this variant I didn't  achive `email` too.

I'm confused. Tell me,  how can I retrieve user email.

3.After login I try:

```
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            System.out.println("succses =" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

            GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    Log.d("TAG", user.optString("email"));
                    Log.d("TAG", user.optString("name"));
                    Log.d("TAG", user.optString("id"));
                    init();
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
```

But I don't  see  `TAG` with  email
P.S. All permissions in `graph explorer` are turned on.

Comment: try this answer on stackoverflow... i was faced same problem... http://stackoverflow.com/a/33412596

Comment: @ExceptionLover yeah thanks. This helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highest voted answer didn't work for me and email was alway empty. i found answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33412596/3678308)

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                            try {
                                if(json != null){
                                    String text = json.getString("email");
                                    Log.d("email",text);

                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
            });
```