# What function is called when a user logs in second time through facebook in my app?

Tags: facebook-login

```
 AuthCredential fbCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(fbCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){....});
```

This what i ve used to to login through facebook.Like this signInWithCredential is there other which needs to be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific function which is called the second time user logs in.But whenever the FacebookLoginButton is clicked the control goes to `facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(fbCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {...}`.
You can override the `onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)`{} function if in which you can find if the user has already registered through facebook.
Rest information you can get from this post for extracting the email from firebase auth.
[Facebook Graph solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33412596/5829494)

Comment: Yeah i tried that.It was a workaround but did my work.Thanks.