# Not able to get profile details from Facebook on Android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to get the profile details from Facebook. I am using the latest Facebook SDK. I want to use custom login button to login and get profile details of user.

In onSuccess method i am getting LoginSuccess object . Now i am stuck how i got user profile data . And this code is on facebookButton not on custom button. Please give me some ideas to integrate the SDK via custom button. I go through the facebook documentation but do not got anything useful.

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get simple user info (like name and id) by using in `onSuccess()` loginManager method [Profile class](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Profile/):

```
Profile.getCurrentProfile() //get current instance of logged profile
Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId() //get current id
Profile.getCurrentProfile().getName() //get current user name
```

If you want to fetch more information about user, like email or date of birth, you should to use GraphAPI request. You can read about it in related [question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29379794/4671372).

It doesn't matter, if you are using Custom Login button or not. In both situations SDK is using loginManager.