# is it possible to get username, email , date of birth from facebook sdk auth module

Tags: android, kotlin

i've implemented the facebook auth now i want to get the email , username , date of birth in the app of that user 
FB module https://github.com/betranthanh/android-kotlin-loginfacebook

Comment: have you read the docs for the facebook sdk?

Comment: Email : Yes, Username : Yes, Date of birth : NO, you only get to know the age range of the person

Comment: @DominikWuttke sir can u please share any related stuff for doing that work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295987/android-facebook-4-0-sdk-how-to-get-email-date-of-birth-and-gender-of-user/46831673

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my own problem it looks something like this

this is my onClick listener of FB loginButton

'fun facebook(view: View) {

```
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
    Profile.getCurrentProfile()

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
        object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {

                handleFacebookToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken())

               // Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook token: " + loginResult.accessToken.token)
               // Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook id: "  + loginResult.accessToken.userId)
                startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, LoginActivity::class.java))


            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook onCancel.")

            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook onError.")

            }
        })
}
```

//this is my FacebookHandler `private fun handleFacebookToken(accessToken: AccessToken) {
      val  profile =  Profile.getCurrentProfile()
        if (profile != null){

```
       val firstName = profile.firstName
        val lastname = profile.middleName
        val email = profile.id

        Log.d("MainActivity","first name : $firstName")
        Log.d("MainActivity","full name : $lastname")
        Log.d("MainActivity","id : $email")
        idName.setText(firstName)

    }
}`
```